# Select previous and next words when double clicking blank space in HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text, cpu-word, selection

I was trying to change the behaviour of an HTML page with Javascript so whenever I click a blank space in a text (not textArea) between two words, instead of selecting that blank space, it selects the words before and after the blank space. I was trying to do it this way, but I am not able to do it:

```
function getBothWords() {
  if (window.getSelection()) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var blank = " ";
    if(sel == blank) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I also was trying to play with:

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
```

But still nothing. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try debugging this? Stepping through the function to see what the values of the variables are? What is `sel` when you are trying to loosely compare it to a blank space.

Comment: The selection is working fine. 'sel' is whatever I select double-clicking, so if I select a blank space (yes, maybe the comparison is a bit tricky) it goes inside that 'if'. The problem is that I do not know how to add to the selection the previous word and the one after the blank space.

Comment: I said loosely because you're only doing `==`. To properly compare values in javascript you should use the strict equals operator `===` which will also compare type to prevent implicit conversion to boolean values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an **amazing** method in class `Selection` called `modify()` which is created for that purpose. In my case, the solution would be:

```
function select() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    var s = window.getSelection();
    var blank = " ";
    if(s == blank) {
      selectBothWords(s);
    }
  }
}

function selectBothWords(s) {
    s.modify("move", "backward", "word");
    s.modify("extend", "forward", "word");
    s.modify("extend", "forward", "word");
}
```

The function `select()` checks that the selection is a 'blank space' (loosely). Then, the function `selectBothWords()` uses modify to move the selection one word backwards, then, extend it two words forward.

Answer (score 3):

When you only click on a blank space, the selection will be collapsed. You can try something like this:

```
function getBothWords() {
    var sel,
        range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    if (range.collapsed) {
        range.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset + 1);
    }
    sel = range.toString();
    if (sel ===  ' ') {
        ...
    }
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NL656/).

Answer (score 1):

You should introspect the selection object and see that there is an `anchorNode` element available and an `anchorIndex`.

See the [MDN Docs on `selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FSelection).

The short is you need to look at your `anchorNode` and `anchorOffset`.

`sel.anchorNode.nodeValue[sel.anchorNode.anchorOffset]` **might** be the first character of your selection. Log the `sel` object to the console and start poking around. Some simple math should solve the issue from there. Of course it might not be a text node.

Be sure to read the definitions on the page since there are some gotchas that can be confusing.

More to the point, something like this is a dirty hack job:

```
var subLen = s.focusNode.nodeValue.substr(s.focusOffset).trim().indexOf(' ')+2;
var selectedWordWitSurroundingSpaces = s.focusNode.nodeValue.substr(s.focusOffset, subLen);
```

Comment: I managed to find my way through your answer. In the end it was a bit different and a lot easier! Thanks :)

Comment: "sel.anchorNode.nodeValue[sel.anchorNode.anchorOffset] is the first character of your selection" is not necessarily true: you're assuming `anchorNode` is guaranteed to be a text node, which is not the case. It could also be an element.